# Unable to decode the urlMapping in Grails application

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Problem:
  I am able to execute the default action(listLatest) of my Controller(ReviewMetricsController). But, I am not able to explicitly invoke other action(index) with **form submission**.
I am using Grails 2.0.4 and running my application in development mode from Eclipse IDE with Grails plugin installed.

Detail:
I have a form in my gsp as shown below

```
    <g:form name="queryForm"
        url="[controller:'reviewMetrics', action:'index']">
        <g:actionSubmit value="submit" />
    </g:form>
```

When I submit the above form, I get 404 error

```
The requested resource (/reviewmetricsapp/reviewMetrics/index) is not available
```

My Controller(`reviewMetricsController.groovy`) looks as shown below

```
package reviewmetricsapp

class ReviewMetricsController {

    static scope = "session"
    static defaultAction = "listLatest"
    def gatherMetricsService
    def grailsApplication
    def latestMetrics

    def index() {
        render(view:"dashboard", model: [model: latestMetrics])
    }

    def listLatest(){
        println grailsApplication.config.metricsapp.perlScript.loc
        latestMetrics = gatherMetricsService.getLastWeekMetrics()
        println "printing ${latestMetrics}"
        render(view:"showMetrics", model: [metrics: latestMetrics])
    }

}
```

And my `urlMappings.groovy` looks as shown below

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{ constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            } }

        "/reviewMetrics/index"{
            controller="reviewMetrics"
            action="index"
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need to change the `URLMappings`-file for your use-case. (remove the special case handling for reviewMetrics/index - its handled from the first rule)
2. Please use the following form definition:

   ```
   <g:form name="queryForm"
      controller="reviewMetrics"
      action="index">
      [..]
   </g:form>
   ```
3. Please double check that your action is not accessed - simply put a plain `index.gsp` and do not care inside the controller. I guess the error is somewhere else.

Comment: No luck after trying the above too!! Using g:link works. I made one observation. When I hover over the submit button it shows /reviewmetricsapp/reviewMetrics/index but when I hover over a link, it shows http://localhost:8080/reviewmetricsapp/reviewMetrics/index. The link works but the form submit does not